# TypeError with JSON requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests

```
import requests

user = 'my_user'
pwd = 'my_pwd'
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"application/json"}

url = 'https://my_company.service-now.com/api/now/table/sc_req_item/bfa27ef2db203f00d8909c47db9619f3?sysparm_fields=sys_id%2Crequest'

response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers  )
mydata = response.json()
print(mydata)                  #Print for debug output purposes
for item in mydata["result"]:
    print(item["sys_id"])
    print(item["request"]["value"])
```

Output from `print(mydata)`:

```
{'result': {'sys_id': 'bfa27ef2db203f00d8909c47db9619f3', 'request': {'link': 'https://my_company.service-now.com/api/now/table/sc_request/3fa27ef2db203f00d8909c47db9619f3', 'value': '3fa27ef2db203f00d8909c47db9619f3'}}}
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prod_getUnapprovedSIDs.py", line 42, in <module>
    print(item["sys_id"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: `mydata["result"]` is a **dictionary**. Iterating over it iterates over the *keys*, so `item` is e.g. `"sys_id"` and `"sys_id"["sys_id"]` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the `key, value` pairs of the JSON response. Try this example instead:

```py
for key, item in mydata.items():
    print(item["sys_id"])
    print(item["request"]["value"])
```